# recvmsg with select on NETLINK socket

Tags: c, select, netlink, ipsec

I am writing NETLINK xfrm socket programming to create association and policies for ESP communication. To send the data to kernel

```
sockfd = socket(AF_NETLINK, SOCK_RAW|SOCK_CLOEXEC, NETLINK_XFRM);
setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDBUF, &sckbuff, sizeof(sckbuff));
setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVBUF, &sckbuff, sizeof(sckbuff));
bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr_nl));
...
memset(&msg, 0, sizeof(struct msghdr));
msg.msg_name = (void *)&(addr);
msg.msg_namelen = sizeof(addr);
...
memset(&iov, 0, sizeof(struct iovec));
iov.iov_base = (void *)netlink_req;
iov.iov_len = netlink_req->nlmsg_len;

msg.msg_iov = &iov;
msg.msg_iovlen = 1;

sendmsg(sockfd, &msg, 0);
```

And to receive the response from kernel

```
while(true)
{
  ...
  FD_ZERO(&readfds);
  FD_SET(sockfd, &readfds);
  select(sockfd+1, &readfds, NULL, NULL, NULL);

  read_len = recvmsg(sockfd, &msg, MSG_PEEK);
  printf("Data received %d\n", read_len);
  for (nh = (struct nlmsghdr *) buf;
     NLMSG_OK (nh, read_len);
     nh = NLMSG_NEXT (nh, read_len))
  {
    if (nh->nlmsg_type == NLMSG_DONE)
    {
          break;
    }
    else if (nh->nlmsg_type == NLMSG_ERROR)
    {
      ...
    }
    ...
  }
}
...
```

It is working file if recvmsg is done sequentially without `select`.

But when i tried to send multiple request and do `select` with `sockfd` in another thread then `recvmsg` continue to receive the same message and never stop.

Is there any flag i need to set in response to stop the continuous loop or any other way?

Comment: Please, share the code with `select`, since it is the code you are having issues with.

Comment: @RobertoCaboni, Hi i have updated the code with `select`. Code is continuously printing the line `Data received 32` with same data

Comment: You're using `MSG_PEEK`, which doesn't dequeue data. Why wouldn't it give the same result? (Also, if you're using select, check the actual returned value (return and set contents))

Comment: @Hasturkun nice catch. Would you expand your comment into an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`recvmsg()`, when called with the `MSG_PEEK` flag, returns data but doesn't remove it from the socket's receive queue, leading to the next receive returning the same data again.

Remove the flag (or perform a second call for the same size without it) to ensure you get the following messages.

I'd also highly recommend checking the return from `select()` as well as the updated set (since `select()` can return without a readable socket in this case, e.g. if a signal is caught).
I'd also note that in your current usage, `select()` isn't giving you much over a plain blocking `recvmsg()` call.

Comment: Thanks @Hasturkun, deleting the `MSG_PEEK` do the work for me.